# rvm on live server

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

I'm using RVM on my development machine for my Ruby on Rails application which works really well.  My question is should I (can I) use RVM on my live server for deployment?

I already have the web app up on a live server using Passenger but I have just installed Ruby and all the gems on the system.

Are there any performance issues with RVM and is there much that I would need to do with my Apache web server to get it up and running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance of ruby compiled manually and with RVM - should be the same (unless you uses patches like `patchexpress` or `falcon`).

You can use RVM for deployment - you can do it together with updating ruby version / patchlevel, it's very important to use the latest patchlevel as it contains important fixes for ruby - including security fixes.

As for integration of RVM compiled Rubies - read the docs: https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/

Comment: Great thanks for that, I was mainly concerned by performance issues